# Countdown module that hides an element when a specified date is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, revealing-module-pattern

I have the following piece of code which hides an element when a specified date was reached. I would like to get some tips about do's and don'ts.

Specifically, I'm interested in:

- improvements brought to this code
- avoid bad practices

And whatever you guys consider I should be careful about.

```
var Timer = (function(){
    var $el = $('#element');

    function count() {
        setInterval(function() {
            check();
        }, 1000);
    }

    function hide() {
        $el.hide();
    }

    function check() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var endingDate = new Date("July 25, 2016 11:06:00");

        if (currentDate.getTime() >= endingDate.getTime()) { 
            hide();
        }
    }


    return {
        count: count  
    };
})();

Timer.count();
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview! What should we do with this code ? Please [edit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/135192/edit) your question and add some information about what the code does and what would you like to improve about it. You can also look in our help section at [_How do I ask a good question?_](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks

Comment: @Dex'ter I would like suggestions on how I can make it better.

Comment: You should include more information in the queston's body

Comment: There is no way this code works. `CountDown` is an intervalId so it won't have a run function. You've either copied your code incorrectly or haven't tested it (come back when it's working though!)

Comment: @RobH I think I copied it wrong. I will updated it in a few hours. Is there a way to hide the post until then?

Comment: No - you could delete and post again later but not sure whether there's a rule/convention...

Comment: @RobH Ok, well... I updated it.

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo I updated it

Answer (score 1):

My notes:

- There is no need to create a function that calls `check`, you can just pass `check`
- There is no need for function `hide`, you only call it once, and it only has 1 line of code, I would inline that function
- Very minor, but there is no need to declare `endingDate` inside `check`, I would declare it once outside of the function
- You are using a revealing pattern, I would use a simple self executing pattern. On the whole if you expose 1 function that you will run only once, use a self executing function.
- Once the date is passed you will be hiding that element non-stop every second, that sounds like overkill
- I abhor anonymous functions, choose a meaningful name, and you can spare a line of comment ;)

My approach with these notes would be

```
    (function HideElementWhenTimeComes (){
      var $el = $('#element'),
          endingDate = new Date("July 25, 2016 11:06:00"),
          intervalID;

      function check() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
            if (currentDate.getTime() >= endingDate.getTime()) { 
              $el.hide();
              clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
      }

      intervalID = setInterval(check , 1000 );

    })();
```